# Model failing to receive call from method even though the method is being called in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm trying to write a test to see if my Hospital model is receiving a custom method look_for_hospitals.

Here is the test:

```rb
Rspec.describe HospitalsController, type: :controller do
    describe '#search' do
        it 'should call the model method to do the search' do
            # model should implement method look_for_hospitals
            expect(Hospital).to receive(:look_for_hospitals).with('keyword')
            # form in search page must be named 'keywords'
            get :search, params: {:keywords => 'keyword'}
            expect(assigns(:hospitals))
        end
    end
```

Here is my model:

```rb
class Hospital<ApplicationRecord
    def self.look_for_hospitals term
    end
end
```

And here is the method search in the HospitalsController:

```rb
def search
    keyword = params[:keywords]
    @hospitals = Hospital.look_for_hospitals(keyword)
end
```

When I run my test this is the error I'm having:

```
  1) HospitalsController#search should call the model method to do the search
     Failure/Error: expect(Hospital).to receive(:look_for_hospitals).with('keyword')

       (Hospital(id: integer, cnes: string, number: integer, address: text, latitude: string, longitude: string, name: string, phones: text, nature: string, specialties: text, rpa: string, microregion: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) (class)).look_for_hospitals("keyword")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("keyword")
           received: 0 times
```

I know there is pretty much nothing implemented yet, but i'm trying the tdd approach of writing the tests first and then the methods.
Sorry if my english is a bit strange, not native english speaker.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? What did you find? The issue could be caused by all manner of things, but I'm pretty certain it's something that you **haven't** shown in the post above. (E.g. Maybe there's a `before_action` on the controller, which means that line of code never gets executed?)

Comment: That was precisely it. Someone added devise to the project and i completely missed the `before_action` line. Thank you so much!

Comment: tricky tricky ..

Comment: If you don't want to close the question feel free to leave your own answer, you can accept it in a few days. This will just help move it along since you already know the answer to it, and answerers won't have to read through it only to realize it's already solved.

Comment: You got it. I'm new here, so sorry if I don't know the protocols yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom Lord pointed out, the problem was in the `before_action` line at the begining of the Controller. I just needed to stub those and the problem was gone.